# Can i make my p5.js draw() function run only once, and then only on a button click?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I have this snippet of p5.js code:

```js
let x = 10;
let y = Math.floor(Math.random()*201);
let x2 = 190;
let y2 = 200 - Math.floor(Math.random()*201);

function setup() {
    createCanvas(200, 200);
}

function draw() {
    clear();
    y = Math.floor(Math.random()*201);
    y2 =  200 - Math.floor(Math.random()*201);
    line(10, y, 190, y2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.js"></script>
```

and I want to make it so that it runs once automatically, then again every time a button is pressed.

My main concern here is the "run only once" bit, so if anyone can help me out with that, it'd be great.

Comment: Do you want it to run automatically once the page loading is completed?
If so, you can use dimple jquery. Or, you want something else?  
$(document).ready( function () {
  draw();
});

Answer (score 6):

[Rabbid76's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58804521/873165) is already correct, but just in case you're curious: you can also use the `noLoop()` and `loop()` functions to control whether `draw()` is continuously called.

Here's an example:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  noLoop();
}

function mousePressed() {
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 25, 25);
}

function keyPressed() {
  loop();
}
```

This code calls the `noLoop()` function to tell p5.js not to call the `draw()` function continuously. This allows you to draw circles with the mouse, without them being cleared by the background. Then when a key is pressed, this code calls the `loop()` function to start calling `draw()` again. This draws a background, and then stops calling the `draw()` function continuously again.

You can find more info in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/).

Answer (score 1):

The [`loop()`/`noLoop()` approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58805899/6243352) is a good option, but I don't see a problem with skipping `draw()` entirely:

```js
let x = 10;
let y;
let x2 = 190;
let y2;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
  renderLine();
}

function mousePressed() {
  renderLine();
}

function keyPressed() {
  renderLine();
}

function renderLine() {
  clear();
  y = floor(random(201));
  y2 = 200 - floor(random(201));
  line(10, y, 190, y2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

... or calling `draw` once with `noLoop()` enabled (to separate it from `setup()` code), then using key or mouse handlers the rest of the way to call `redraw()` which runs `draw()` one time:

```js
let x = 10;
let y;
let x2 = 190;
let y2;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(200, 200);
  noLoop();
}

function draw() {
  clear();
  y = floor(random(201));
  y2 = 200 - floor(random(201));
  line(10, y, 190, y2);
}

function mousePressed() {
  redraw();
}

function keyPressed() {
  redraw();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

[Program flow](https://p5js.org/learn/program-flow.html) from the p5 docs might be helpful for exploring these options.

As a minor aside, since you've imported p5, I'd just use the `floor` and `random` functions they provide.